# Graph API batching with paging?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the PHP Facebook SDK and graph API to get all the likes of all of a user's friends. Problem is it's taking quite a while to execute.

Currently I'm getting all the user's friends, then individually looping through each friend and collecting all their likes.

To speed things up, I want to batch every 50 "/user_friend_fbid/likes" requests (but also do paging for these as well).

i.e. this:

```
foreach (facebookUserFriends($fb_id) as $friend) { //custom func returns friends
    facebookUserLikes($friend['id'],$fb_location); //custom func returns all user likes
}
```

...versus:

```
$i = 0;     
foreach (facebookUserFriends($fb_id) as $friend) {
    $queries[$i]['method'] = 'GET';
    $queries[$i]['relative_url'] = $friend['id'].'/likes';
    if ($i==49) {
       batchProcess($queries); //custom func returns all likes (but doesn't do paging)
       $i = 0;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

***TL;DR how do I perform paging within a batch query?***

Answer (score 1):

That stuff could get ugly really fast ;-)

Use FQL multi-query instead and save both parties some time: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.multiquery/

See here as well:
[Facebook New PHP SDK For Graph API - Multi Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332739/facebook-new-php-sdk-for-graph-api-multi-query)

For your case, a single FQL could suffice:

```
SELECT object_id, user_id FROM like WHERE user_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())
```

That finds the likes for my own friends for instance; substitute `me()` with something else.

Comment: Hmm, that's not a fun language. I've worked out how to retrieve a user's likes and a user's friends, but not all if a friends likes...

Comment: This seems to work, but only returns "MUSICIAN/BAND": SELECT name, type 
FROM page 
WHERE page_id 
IN 
(SELECT page_id 
FROM page_fan 
WHERE uid 
IN 
(SELECT uid2 
FROM friend 
WHERE uid1 = me())) - then filtering by type = "local business" returns 4 results which isn't everything. I've read that FQL doesn't return everything.

Comment: There are certain limitations to FQL, but so far I have not encountered those before :) your data set also seems to be particularly large, which might cause some intermediate results to be capped to an upper limit?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a breadth-first approach. Queue up the first 50 users 1st batch request, and when the batch is returned, save the data, and then create a new batch from the 50 paging urls returned.